# SignalR parallel sending messages

Tags: signalr

Is there any sense in parallel sending messages? (split customers into 2 groups)

```
new Thread(() =>
{
  context.Clients.Clients(listUsers1).LevelI("1 ", d);
}).Start();
new Thread(() =>
{
  context.Clients.Clients(listUsers2).LevelI("1 ", d);
}).Start();
```

or sending messages to all clients

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There should be no need to do that unless you are sending a different message to listUsers1 vs. listUsers2.

SignalR has a fairly high rate of per second message send capability. If the size of the messages exceed the recommended cap you should determine how to reduce the message size.

Generally, neither of those should be an issue you have to worry about as it relates to performance.